# How to remove all the grips on a coolbar if I have several coolbands?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

If I set mycoolbar.fixedorder to true,only the grip on the first band will be hidden.

Well,If you use Delphi 7 to create an VCL Forms application,then put a coolbar on it and create 3 coolbans to hold other controls,only the grip and the top coolbands can be hidden by setting mycoolbar.fixedorder:=true.

I've uploaded a picture to make things clear.[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: @Barranka, there's not much to explain; [`FixedOrder = True`](http://i.imgur.com/eYoTfeG.png), [`FixedOrder = False`](http://i.imgur.com/UZEbUlE.png). The grip on the bottom coolband from the second picture shouldn't be there.

Comment: Setting fixed size on the bands should deliver the wished result.

Comment: @bummi, take a look at what the reference says for the [`RBS_FIXEDORDER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774377(v=vs.85).aspx#RBS_FIXEDORDER) style: *You can move bands to different rows, but the band order is static.*, so I think this behavior is by design. If I get the question right :-)

Comment: @TLama I agree with "by design", my focus was on the desire to hide the grips.

Comment: Thanks you all guys.I've edited the post. Apperently if one grip could be hidden,then all can be hidden,I just don't know how.

Comment: @user2349181, the `TCoolBar` is a Delphi implementation of a [`Rebar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774375(v=vs.85).aspx) control and that's how this control behaves in Windows. As I've mentioned in my previous comment, there is a note at the `RBS_FIXEDORDER` style (which is in Delphi included by setting the `FixedOrder` to True), *You can move bands to different rows, but the band order is static.*, so in fact it's an intended behavior. Sorry, I've no time for posting answers these days (I'm using comments instead).

Comment: @TLama,but WinRAR can do it.How could it be possible?

Comment: @user2349181, as @bummi already mentioned, if you don't want to just keep the order of bands (what you've asked for) but lock the toolbar (disable also resizing of the bands), you can set to all the bands `FixedSize` property to True. That will lock the toolbar, just like WinRAR does (hide grips and disable realign of the bands).

Answer (score 0):

You probably got a [FixedOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276531%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) property wrong. The fixed property does not allow bands to be rearranged if set to `True`.

Setting up property of `CoolBar` to `True` keep user from changing the bands order at runtime, but the user can still move and resize the bands. I can actually give you advice what you can do, but the actual solution for your problem, well, you will have to wait for another answer.

My advice is to use three CoolBars in a row and setting their "FixedOrder" property to `True` and BandBorderStyle to `bsNone`. That way the grip will be hidden on all of them.

About the property, it's not a bug of IDE, it is the actual preference of the property.